# Is it possible to call a function of an embeded block in AnyLogic?

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I'm still a basic user of AnyLogic and JAVA and I have the problem to get the remaining time of a service block. I know that the service block embeded the delay block and there is a function for the delay (getRemainingTime(agent)). Is it possible to call this function in (Agent) Main?

I need to get the time my product will stay in the service block to navigate my pushing processes. I have 3 products (all are individuall agents) and a pickup-block before the service to assemble my products and 1 raw material(individual agent aswell). Obviously the remaining time has to be dynamic and needs to be reseted after the agent exits the service block.

I use the service block to connect my ressources direct and (if not neccessary) I don't want to use the delay block itself.
Unfortunately I couldn't finde any simular queistions/explanations to this topic and I hope you can help me.

Thank you very much.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the remaining time within a service block, simply use `myServiceBlock.delay.getRemainingTime(agent))`, assuming your Service block is named "myServiceBlock"

You can call it from any place (including Main). The specifics depend on your model structure, see [this help article](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fcode%2FAccess.html&resultof=%22%77%68%65%72%65%22%20%22%61%6D%22%20%22%69%22%20).